# Is there a way in RSpec to give 'not' higher precedence than the all matcher?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

RSpec 3 provids the [all matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/built-in-matchers/all-matcher). For example,

```
expect(['Tom', 'Tony', 'Rosa']).to all( include("o") )
```

You can also have

```
expect(['Tom', 'Tony', 'Rosa']).to_not all( include("o") )
```

But how do you express "to all not"?

Comment: I think you mean `include`, not `contain`, so editing accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a negated version of the matcher with which you want to test each element of the list, for example,

```
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :exclude, :include
```

and use it like

```
expect(%w(Tom Tony Rosa)).to all(exclude('o'))
```

Comment: This is a good alternative.  It has clean and simple semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation and a quick perusal of the code, there appears to be no built in `all_not` matcher, so one would have to iterate over the array to achieve the result, as follows:

```
['Tom', 'Tony', 'Rosa'].each { |name| expect(name).to_not contain('o') }
```

You can view the built-in matchers, including `all` at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/9ff22694fa88cb0b0e794b6f99f3cfacfa909bf4/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/all.rb